# Neo4j: Step by Step to create an automatic index

Tags: database, indexing, neo4j, cypher, database-indexes

I am creating a new Neo4j database. I have a type of node called User and I would like an index on the properties of user **Identifier** and **EmailAddress**. How does one go setting up an index when the database is new? I have noticed in the neo4j.properties file there looks to be support for creating indexes. However when I set these as so

```
# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=EmailAddress,Identifier
```

And add a node and do a query to find an Identifier that I know exists

```
START n=node:Identifier(Identifier = "USER0")
RETURN n;
```

then I get an

```
MissingIndexException: Index `Identifier` does not exist
```

How do I create an index and use it in a start query? I only want to use config files and cypher to achieve this. i.e. at the present time I am only playing in the Power Tool Console.

Comment: Make sure to see Boggle's answer below - how indexes work is significantly simpler in 2.0+ - and as you say it's a new database, so hopefully moving to the latest neo4j version is an option...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add the following to the neo4j.properties file

```
# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=EmailAddress,Identifier
```

Create the auto index for nodes

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ index --create node_auto_index -t Node
```

Check if they exist

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ index --indexes
```

Should return

```
Node indexes:
node_auto_index
```

When querying use the following syntax to specify the index

```
start a = node:node_auto_index(Identifier="USER0")
return a;
```

As the node is auto indexed the name of the index is `node_auto_index`

This information came from a comment at the bottom of [this page](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html)

**Update**

In case you want to index your current data which was there before automatic indexing was turned on (where Property_Name is the name of your index)

```
START nd =node(*) 
WHERE has(nd.Property_Name)
WITH nd
SET nd.Property_Name = nd.Property_Name
RETURN count(nd);
```

Comment: [how to start up neo4j-sh on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19275558/1174169)

Comment: Use http://localhost:7474/webadmin. After page loads select the console tab. you can execute the shell commands there.

Comment: This answer is really old and i'm not sure if this is still the best way to do this. Some clarification on this would be good.

Answer (score 9):

Indexes mainly made on property which is used for where condition. In Neo4j 2.0, indexes are easy to make now.

Create index on a label

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

Drop index on a label

```
DROP INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

Create uniqueness constraint

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (book:Book) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

Drop uniqueness constraint

```
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (book:Book) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

For listing all indexes and constraints in neo4j-browser, following command is useful

```
:schema
```

List indices and constraints for specific label with:

```
:schema ls -l :YourLabel
```

Answer (score 8):

In Neo4j 2.0, you should use labels and the new constraints instead

```
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:User) ASSERT n.Identifier IS UNIQUE
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:User) ASSERT n.EmailAddress IS UNIQUE
```

If email isn't unique per user, just create a plain index instead:

```
    CREATE INDEX ON :User(EmailAddress)
```