# Neo4j Embedded - Auto Index Multiple Properties

Tags: neo4j

I turned on node auto-indexing and it's indexing the properties I need. If I start up the Neo4j server and open the webadmin, I see that there is an index called `node_auto_index` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877678/neo4j-step-by-step-to-create-an-automatic-index) post. It works perfectly from the webadmin and I can run Cypher queries like this:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index('__type:user AND __username:admin') RETURN n
```

The query returns exactly what I expect. However, if I shut down the server and open the DB in embedded mode from a Scala application, this doesn't work. If I try to run the same Cypher query, I get an error that `node_auto_index` doesn't exist. I checked the GraphDatabaseService properties, and auto indexing is up and running on the right keys, but when getting a list of all of the index names, the list is always empty. And I can't use the AutoIndex API because it only indexes on one property, and I definitely need both.

So from this point, what would be the best way to ago about querying the auto-index with multiple properties from my Scala (Java) code?

EDIT: I noticed that the ReadableIndex interface (which is what the auto-index is) can take a query string. I can't find much documentation on it, so I'm going to try a few things, but is there any chance that could take a Cypher query? Or just the single-quoted string in my query above?

Comment: What code are you using to run the Cypher query from Scala?

Comment: I'm using this exact code: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-java.html. But I actually just figured out my issue. I'll answer my own question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the `query` function of the ReadableIndex actually takes a [Lucene Query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html), which I now realize is what I had quoted above. So calling this code:

```
val nodes = db.index.getNodeAutoIndexer.getAutoIndex.query("__type:user AND __username:admin")
```

Gave me exactly what I wanted.