# Indexing nodes in Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I've been reading up on and implementing Neo4j's graph database technology.

It's pretty cool and powerful my only concern is there seems to be a lack on documentation and/or how to tutorials for beginners.

On trying to understand indexing I found that in the webadmin there is a section entitled 'Add and remove indexes' which does just that. However, what I can't find is how to actually implement indexing.

How do I add a node making sure that it is in the correct index and has the correct properties indexed?

N.B. I am using Cypher to do all my graph transactions due to there not being (or at least there not being a good) Objective C API.

**EDIT**

I should note that I have tried the steps found here: [Neo4j: Step by Step to create an automatic index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877678/neo4j-step-by-step-to-create-an-automatic-index?rq=1)
but when I perform the query, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j supports auto-indexing (which is what you were looking at) which is less flexible than the other alternative which provides the user more control. Learn about it [in this tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-schema.html). You can see a reference to legacy indexing tutorial in the provided link. If you are using older versions than 2.0 then go through the legacy tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Also, keep in mind that when you create an index **it does not apply to the existing nodes**, it only applies to the nodes that you will create from now on.