# Problems with Neo4j.rb and node_auto_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, cypher

I am having some problems with my neo4j rails project. I am trying to get a query to work, but I keep getting `Index 'node_auto_index' does not exist`. I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877678/neo4j-step-by-step-to-create-an-automatic-index) that appears to solve this if you were running a separate neo4j server. However I am not, I am using the neo4j.rb gem which fixes all this for me, so there is no `neo4j.properties` file anywhere.

I though the neo4j.properties were mirrored in the `config/application.rb`, but when I try to do `config.neo4j.node_auto_indexing = true` it does not help.

The cypher query I am trying to do is done like this:

```
@q = Neo4j._query("CYPHER 1.9 START n=node:node_auto_index('name:*{query}*') 
                  MATCH (n)-[r:CONNECTED*0..6]-(tag) 
                  RETURN reduce(sum = 1, ni IN r: sum * ni.price) LIMIT 6", 'query' => params[:query])
#I have tried with and without the "CYPHER 1.9" part.
```

How can I solve this? Is there a lucene way of doing the same kind of request? Note the use of `reduce` which is important.

Is there a way to get the node_auto_index to work in Neo4j.rb?

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

---

Versions:

- jRuby 1.7.4
- gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
- gem 'neo4j', '2.3.0-java'

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your autoindex before you can query it. If your db isn't too big, try running this:

```
start n=node(*) 
set n.name=n.name;
```

Also, I noticed you're multiplying the prices in the `reduce`--looks like you're calculating a sum, so you probably want to use the `+` operator.

Comment: I am having some issues with this. I am getting `property name does not exist on Node[0]`. When adding `where id(n) <> 0`, I get the same issue for `Node[1]`. Any idea how to fix this? And, yeah, the multiplication is right. I am not doing sum per say, I am doing some stuff with these weights.

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to check whether the property exists.
`start n=node(*)
where has(n.name) 
set n.name=n.name;`

Comment: This does not help with the `node_auto_index` unfortunately.

Comment: you also need to set the keys that you are indexing in the auto index in the initial config.