# Neo4j 1.9.4 Windows Installer- where did the shell go?

Tags: neo4j

When you install 1.9.4 using the new Windows installer, from where does one launch the Neo4j-Shell (previously found in bin)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The neo4j-shell isn't currently shipping with the neo4j desktop but you can launch it by running the following command from 'C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\' (or equivalent location:):

```
jre\bin\java -classpath bin\neo4j-desktop-1.9.4.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient
```

I'm not sure whether there are plans to include it in the next release, I'll check.

Comment: this worked for me, but I had to add `-classpath` before the jar:  `java -classpath neo4j-desktop-2.0.0-RC1.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient` and on Windows had to start the command prompt as Administrator to get [the shell to echo text properly](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/11/29/neo4j-the-case-of-windows-neo4j-desktop-and-the-invisible-text/)

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall your neo4j windowns instalation version, so you can download an zip file with contains the neo4j binary version for Windows at http://www.neo4j.org/download. Using this version, you can find the bin, conf and lib folder. Besides that, you can find the Neo4jShell.bat. This file is the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the stand alone Neo4j-Shell isn't included in the installer for 1.9.4, but there is the Power tool console in the web interface, and you can also use the shell from the 1.8.3 package. I have no idea if it's supported though, but it seems to work.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have clarified that the webadmin shell does work. However I was looking at reading and executing a file of cypher statements via the shell. Will check whether the 1.8.3 shell works for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers who end up here, there is a cypher shell at `<neo4_dir>\bin\cypher-shell.bat`. Neo4j-CE-3.1.0