# Not able to see Neo4j Shell in the installation directory

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**I'm using Neo4j 2.1.4 Community Edition.**

I'm able to write cypher queries in neo4j browser. If I switch from neo4j browser to Webadmin ,there are 5 tabs where you can see `Console` . So is it a Neo4j Shell? In neo4j manual it is given that neo4j shell should be started from its installation directory i.e.,`./bin/neo4j-shell` , but i can not see the neo4j-shell option under /bin directory. Is it available only in enterprise edition?

Also in the neo4j manual it is said that the commands like `cd,ls,pwd`   but I'm not able to run these commands in neo4j wedadmin console.. Is Console providing all the neo4j shell features or it is only meant for specific commands(limited features).

Please clarify the above quesries

**Updates:** Below is the Neo4j installation directory and i'm using windows7
[image]
[image]
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Neo4j 1.9.4 Windows Installer- where did the shell go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255500/neo4j-1-9-4-windows-installer-where-did-the-shell-go)

Answer (score 0):

What OS did you install it on? And how?

If you did debian package then neo4j-shell is available on your path.
The bin directory is where you unzipped the Neo4j download.

You should also be able to run the commands listed (ls etc.) in the "Console" tab of the `http://localhost:7474/webadmin` UI

Comment: Michael@, i'm using Windows7 OS. So how can i start Neo4j_shell from the installation directory. And also in Web interface console if I run the command `ls` alone it gives me an error and if i run `ls -rfv KNOWS:out 197` it give me some result. Is it like can't we run the commands like `ls,pwd, cd` alone in the neo4j console ?

Comment: Check out Mark's blog post for details on how to run Neo4jShell on windows with the installer: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/11/29/neo4j-the-case-of-windows-neo4j-desktop-and-the-invisible-text/