# Neo4J - how to auto index relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created auto relationship index as [described on Neo4J website](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html) and when I get a list of the current relationship indexes using

```
 curl -i http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/auto/relationship/status
```

I get TRUE

Then when I list the properties of relationships indexed using

```
 curl -i http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/auto/relationship/properties
```

I get a list, which is correct:

```
 [ "statement", "context", "gapscan", "user" ]
```

(these are the properties of my relationship)

Finally, and that's what **doesn't work** - when I try to see all the relationships where the property gapscan (key=2 as above) equals '4' using

```
curl -i http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship/relationship_auto_index/gapscan/4
```

I don't get any results – it's empty.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? Isn't GET request to the link above supposed to show me all the relationships matching?

**UPDATE:**

Turned out I was using the wrong {key} in the URL, but the problem still persists for the old relationships that were in the system before I added auto index. How do I index them?

Answer (score 2):

Asking a question is the best way to solve it... Turned out that the way to do it is to run the following query on every relationship property:

```
 START rel=relationship(*)
 WHERE has(rel.gapscan)
 WITH rel
 SET rel.gapscan = rel.gapscan
 RETURN count(rel);
```

(as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877678/neo4j-step-by-step-to-create-an-automatic-index) for nodes)